# QGIS Join vector point into polygon's

Tags: qgis, vector, point

I have groups of vector points (GPS points) in a number of layers in QGIS.  I would like to connect the points in each layer into polygons in each individual layer.  I have look hard, but can not find away within QGIS to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need the "points to path tool" from the processing menu, I think you mean lines not polygons?

If you want a polygon use the buffer tool from VECTOR/GEOPROCESSING TOOLS menu to create a buffer around your points.

Comment: If the points make a complete ring (ie the final point is exactly the same as the starting point) you can use the `lines to polygons` tool to convert the lines into polygons.

Comment: Thank you ... just what I was after (magic) using the 'points to path' and 'lines to polygons' tools.  I can now mark all my Archaeology Field Project Trench in on the maps from my GPS points :-)